# array_push overwritting array data

Tags: php, arrays

Okay so I am attempting to make a little sticky note type program

```
    $c = $_GET['post'];
    $x = $_GET['submit'];
    $a = array();
    if(isset($x)){
    array_push($a , $c);
    var_dump($a);
```

however every time I submit the form it replaces the data in the array
so instead of ($y,$y,$y) I get ($y)
sorry if I didnt explain that well. php noob you caught me!

Comment: You better show some code, so we can guide you into figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: that's exactly how PHP is SUPPOSED to work. just because you created a var and put something it on request #1, doesn't mean that var will be there for requests #2,3,etc... every run of a php script is completely independent of every other run.

Comment: new to this site as well didn't understand the formatting instructions at first :D

Comment: So then how do I go about adding new post to the end of the array?

Comment: @Georgie - You need to persist the data from the array somewhere: database, file, caching system like redis, whereever

Comment: There is another way which is to store the data in a form hidden field.

Comment: @Mark Baker - Thank you! I was so intent on doing it without the database but it seems like that's pointless. I appreciate your advice